# Как сделать функцию удобной?

Tags: c++, функции

Есть такой код:

```
auto Karrr =make_shared<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>(size1, vector<vector<int>>(size2, vector<int>(size3)));
```

Он создает многомерный массив.

Вот так вызвать:

```
(*Karrr)[1][1][1];
```

Я бы хотел сделать его создание как-то удобней.

Например так:

```
auto arr2 = make_shared2(size,size2,size3);
```

Ещё изменить `(*Karrr)`, на просто `Karrr`, если это возможно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, изложите ваш вопрос более понятно и корректно. Тот код, что вы привели, ничего не создаст, потому что не скомпилируется :( Чего именно вы хотите добиться? Словом, прочтите это - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

Ну, если хотите - то можно написать свою функцию. Например,

```
shared_ptr<vector<vector<vector<int>>>> make_shared2(size_t s1, size_t s2, size_t s3)
{
    return make_shared<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>(s1, 
                       vector<vector<int>>(s2, vector<int>(s3)));
}
```

после чего вызывать ее именно так, как написали:

```
auto arr2 = make_shared2(size,size2,size3);
```

Чтобы не тягать за собой `*`, можно воспользоваться, например, ссылкой:

```
vector<vector<vector<int>>>& arr = *arr2;
```

и работать как с обычным массивом

```
arr[i][j][k];
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

Comment: make_shared2 не знает что такое size1, size2 и size3. Ведь имена параметров s1, s2 и s3

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup А, ну да - лень было набирать, copy-paste... Спасибо!